# MySQL Workbench 8.0 - Error 1142 & Error Code: 1370

Tags: permissions, mysql, users, mysql-workbench

I have created a user 'user1'@'localhost'. 
then granted all privileges to the user1 with grant option. any help?
then I go and make a connection of user1 to the database and it keeps throwing error 1142 & 1370.
I have also tried to specifically grant the select & execute privilege as well. and refresh everything in MySQL. However, it still gives the same error.
here is the error.

Error loading schema content    Error Code: 1142 SELECT command denied to user 'book'@'localhost' for table 'user_variables_by_thread'

Error Code: 1370. execute command denied to user 'book'@'localhost' for routine 'e2.min'    0.000 sec

is there anything that I have missed or not getting correct?

Answer (score 0):

well. apparently granting the privileges using the root account did not work. however, in MySQL, going under 'administration' > "users and privileges' and then granting all the privileges from there solved the error and now it allows 'user1' to perform any task on the database.